# Is mysql connector in GlassFish is so buggy or is it just me?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish, mysql-connector

I'm using (trying) GlassFish v2.1.1 + MySQL connector 5.0.8 to teach myself J2EE. I try to develop some simple Web application with JPA persistence. Just when the server starts, deploys go smooth and everything, but after several deploys it starts acting weird, throwing all kind of exceptions and failing predeploy.

For example, on deploy it could throw ClassNotFoundException about class which is even not there anymore (but was there several deploys ago)!

I would have gathered it was my fault (some misconfiguration maybe) if it didn't deploy smoothly again after server restart. I just get the exception, restart the server, and bam - "Command deploy executed successfully". :-\

But maybe there's some intricate dependencies left in runtime, I don't know. Simply undeploying module and deploying it again does not help.

Comment: What tools are you using? For me in Eclipse + GF plugin, rightclicking the server and choosing *Clean* works fine in such circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is subjective but to my experience, redeploys always become unstable at some point. Sometimes things don't get cleaned as they should, sometimes some parts don't release memory as they should, sometime you get an explicit `PermGen` error, etc and at some point, you have to restart the server (which is also why some people never use redeploy in production). I live with that.

That said, to strictly answer the title of your question, I consider GlassFish 2 and the MySQL Connector as **very** stable and totally production ready. But as hinted, development and production do not stress a platform the same way.

Comment: Ditto.. the restart suggestion. We have some XML code that gets all wacky every deploy unless we restart.

Comment: What worries me is whether these things happen due to my fault (faulty module, I don't know, maybe some post-deploy actions are needed to be written somehow) - so my actions are required - or is it just a thing you have to live with?

Comment: @Andy No, there is no extra stuff required to use a built-in connection pool.